# Want to check any entered 4digit resource id is present in openpages or not using java

Tags: java, resource-id, openpages

On entry of 4digit number it should check whether that resource Id is present in openpages or not.if not present then throw error.

I tried using api.get ResourceId(name) but eclipse was not supporting api.auggeat alternative method.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.